# Collection View Multiple horizontal Section Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a `CollectionView` header having horizontal header section but the problem is the section that is being created is vertical and I want everything to be dynamic.

And for this purpose i am using `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` :-

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

        DepartmentCollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        //label.tag = indexPath.row;
        headerView.officeName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_officelist[indexPath.row]];
        [self.roadmapCollectionView addSubview:headerView.officeName];
        reusableview = headerView;
    }

    return reusableview;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use a custom layout?

Comment: i am using flow layout

Comment: you can add a collectionview with horizontal scroll inside the header (i.e. UICollectionReusableView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine(here we are creating labels and buttons in `collection view header` according to the figure) :-

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGFloat x=0,y=0;

    for (int i = 0;i<[_officelist count];i++)
    {
        id val=[officeSize objectAtIndex:i];
        CGFloat val1=[val floatValue];
            UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 10,val1-1,35)];

            newLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_officelist[i]];

            newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

            newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            [self.roadmapCollectionView addSubview:newLabel];

        x=x+val1+1;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<_departmentlist.count; i++) {

        dept=[_departmentlist objectAtIndex:i];
        id val=[officeSize objectAtIndex:i];
        CGFloat val1=[val floatValue];

        float val2=val1/[dept count];
            //NSLog(@"DEPT SIZE - %f",val2);

            for (int j = 0; j < [dept count]; j++)
            {
                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                button.frame = CGRectMake(y, 50,val2-1, 25);
                [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
                [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dept[j]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [self.roadmapCollectionView addSubview:button];

                [deptSize addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:y]];

                y=y+val2+1;

            }
}

    return reusableView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the below code (using DateFlowLayout)

bool isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation);

```
self.collectionView.frame = isPortrait ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 180) : CGRectMake(0, 60, 246, 595);
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = isPortrait ? DateFlowLayout.new : UICollectionViewFlowLayout.new;
self.flowLayout = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout);

self.flowLayout.scrollDirection = isPortrait ? UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal : UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
self.flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = isPortrait ? CGSizeMake(5, 30) : CGSizeMake(246, 40); //width is margin to the left of the header - must be bigger than 0 to show headers correct.
self.flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = isPortrait ? 10 : 0;
self.flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = isPortrait ? 17 : 7;
self.flowLayout.sectionInset = isPortrait ? UIEdgeInsetsMake(27, 30, 25, 0) : UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 0);
//self.flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(58, 85); //You might need this
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = isPortrait ? NO : YES;
```